# SQLite & Versioning Systems

Tags: sqlite, versioning

**Foreword:** I am *not* trying to write an alternative either to Subversion or to any other versioning system.

I wonder if SQLite has what it takes to replace the usual repositories of versioning systems by a single-file database file where different versions are stored as BLOBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all version control systems use the filesystem.

In fact, one such distributed version control system, [Monotone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_%28software%29), already uses SQLite for storage. The FAQ [Why an embedded SQL database, instead of Berkeley DB?](http://wiki.monotone.ca/FAQ/#index10h1) gives some rational for this choice. The FAQ doesn't address "why not filesystem storage" though.

Even SVN, at least historically, supports an [alternate BDB repository data-store](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05.html#svn-ch-5-sect-1.3). While this is not SQLite it is easy to imagine that SQLite can function as a "super" BDB that supports SQL as an interface. (Actually, [BDB can even be used as an SQLite back-end](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html), for a fee :-)

Keep in mind that, *no matter where* the data (diffs/deltas) is stored it all ends up as some form of "BLOB" -- BDB value, data in a file, or BLOB column in a[n SQLite] database.

Happy coding

Answer (score 7):

[Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org) is a version control system implemented in SQLite. It [uses](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/tech_overview.wiki) a single database, storing the versions as BLOBs.

Comment: According to http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/tech_overview.wiki the bulk of the repository database is stored as BLOBs.

Comment: @ericwa - Thanks, I've amended the answer to say that.